# Express app + WordPress as a subdirectory (Apache)

Tags: node.js, wordpress, apache, express, virtualhost

I have a:

Domain: example.com

Express application running on port 123

WordPress installation in /var/www/wordpress

I would like to run the express application under the domain example.com and the WordPress site as a subdirectory of the domain (example.com/wordpress).

My **Apache 2.4** VirtualHost looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName        example.com

  ProxyPreserveHost on
  ProxyPass         "/" "http://localhost:123/"
  ProxyPassReverse  "/" "http://localhost:123/"

  RewriteRule       "^/wordpress$" "/var/www/wordpress"

  <Directory /var/www/wordpress>
    Options         +FollowSymLinks +Multiviews +Indexes
    AllowOverride   All
    Require         all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The express application (example.com) and all of its routes can be accessed fine, but the WordPress application (www.example.com/wordpress) returns an express 404 (not an Apache 404).

Is this an issue in my VirtualHost, an additional express route I have to define, neither, both, something else?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Express project it's runing in example.com?

Comment: That's correct: When you browse to example.com you get the express project. When you browse to example.com/wordpress you get a 404 from express. In other words, the RewriteRule doesn't seem to be working, as it's not even an Apache 404.